# Site opened with Puppeteer is much slower then in usual Chrome browser

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

So, I wanted to parse some page using Puppeteer, but I realised that it is very slow, many times slower than opening the same website in default Chrome browser.Why does it happen?

```
page.goto('https://rosreestr.ru/wps/portal/p/cc_present/ir_egrn')
```

Comment: Have you tried using a different `waitUntil` value, like this: `page.goto('...', { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' })`

Comment: You can try puppeteer-core with chrome. Let us know if that's faster.

Comment: I don't know about this page, but I've found that some sites seem to throttle browser sessions that they detect as bots. You might try all of the usual bot detection avoidance tricks, like setting a user agent and running headfully to see if that makes a difference. If it does, then this suggests that bot detection is the issue.